# SpringBoot - Mustache - Get template as string

Tags: spring-boot, mustache

I have a `spring-boot` application. I am using `Mustache` as a templating engine to show an html page. I am trying to find a way to use mustache as the templating engine but instead of showing it as an html response, I want to get it as `string` so I can use it in some other functionality. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

try this it worked for me

```
public String render(String text, JSONObject substitutionData, boolean html) throws  IOException {
    MustacheFactory mustacheFactory = new DefaultMustacheFactory();
    Mustache mustache = mustacheFactory.compile(new StringReader(text), "text");

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    mustache.execute(stringWriter, substitutionData.toMap()).flush();

    return stringWriter.toString();

}
```